# 3D Game Geometry

Tags: java, c++, geometry, computational-geometry

I have a simple game that uses a 3D grid representation, something like:

```
Blocks grid[10][10][10];
```

The person in the game is represented by a point and a sight vector:

```
double x,y,z, dx,dy,dz;
```

I draw the grid with 3 nested for loops:

```
for(...) for(...) for(...)
   draw(grid[i][j][k]);
```

The obvious problem with this is when the size of the grid grows within the hundreds, fps drop dramatically. With some intuition, I realized that:

- Blocks that were hidden by other blocks in the grid don't need to be rendered
- Blocks that were not within the person's vision field also don't need to be rendered (ie. blocks that were behind the person)

My question is, given a `grid[][][]`, a person's `x,y,z`, and a sight vector `dx,dy,dz`, how could I figure out which blocks need to be rendered and which don't?

Comment: This is a fairly huge topic, covered well in [Hidden Surface Determination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_surface_determination).

Comment: If you use openGL, or any other 3D library, it does this _culling_ automatically in the final rendering.

Comment: So if I use opengl, then adding geometric optimization will not affect the the overall performance?

Comment: @toto2 That is an extremely misleading/totally wrong statement.  Objects outside of clip space are not drawn on the screen, but they still have to pass through the vertex/geometry processors. Objects that are in clip-space but occluded by other objects are processed as if visible, but the final pixel colour is determined by which object has the lowest zDepth value (i.e the closest) - but it _all_ has to be processed to get to that point.

Comment: @cbamber85 OK, sorry.  Seeing the answer from TreeBranch below, it's not openGL, but some higher level engine that must do the culling.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I looked into using [JMonkeyEngine](http://jmonkeyengine.com/), a 3D game engine, a while back and looked at some of the techniques they employ. From what I remember, they use something called culling. They build a tree structure of everything that exists in the 'world'. The idea then is that you have a subset of this tree that represents the visible objects at any given time. In other words, these are the things that need to be rendered. So, say for example that I have a room with objects in the room. The room is on the tree and the objects in the room are children of the tree. If I am outside of the room, then I prune (remove) this branch of the tree which then means I don't render it. The reason this works so well is that I don't have to evaluate EVERY object in the world to see if it should be rendered, but instead I quickly prune whole portions of the world that I know shouldn't be rendered.

Even better, then when I step inside the room, I trim the entire rest of the world from the tree and then only render the room and all its descendants.

I think a lot of the design decisions that the JMonkeyEngine team made were based on things in David Eberly's book, [3D Game Engine Design](http://books.google.com/books/about/3D_game_engine_design.html?id=T8d4hBklV3UC). I don't know the technical details of how to implement an approach like this, but I bet this book would be a great starting point for you.

Here is an interesting [article](http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/technical/graphics-programming-and-theory/geometry-culling-in-3d-engines-r1212) on some different culling algorithms:

- View Frustum Culling
- Back-face Culling
- Cell-based occlusion culling
- PVS-based arbitrary geometry occlusion culling
- Others

Comment: "In the naive version of this algorithm, every object in the world is tested against the six planes." How would I go about implementing something like this? I'm not particularly interested in complex octree structures, etc.

Comment: If you aren't interested in implementing what is considered a standard approach to the problem you have spelled out in your question, then you may want to adjust your efforts. Rather than trying to do this all yourself, use a library. There are tons in C++ and I know one of the best Java ones is JMonkeyEngine (which I linked above).

Answer (score 1):

First you need a spatial partitioning structure, if you are using uniform block sizes, probably the most effective structure will be an [octree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octree).  Then you will need to write an algorithm that can calculate if a box is on a particular side of (or intersecting) a plane.  Once you have that you can work out which leaf nodes of the octree are inside the six sides of your view frustum - that's *view culling*.  Also using the octree you can determine which blocks occlude others (sometimes called *frustum masking*), but get the first part working first.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're going for a minecraft-y type thing. 
Take a look at [this android minecraft level renderer](http://code.google.com/p/minedroid/source/browse/trunk/MineDroid/src/com/ryanm/minedroid/World.java#255).
The points to note are:

- You only have to draw the faces of blocks that are shared with transparent blocks. e.g.: don't bother drawing the faces between two opaque blocks - the player will never see them.
- You'll probably want to batch up your visible block geometry into chunklets (and stick it into a VBO) and determine visibility on a per-chunklet basis. Finding *exactly which* blocks can be seen will probably take longer than just flinging the VBO at the gpu and accepting the overdraw.
- A flood-fill works pretty well to determine which chunklets are visible - limit the fill using the view frustum, view direction (if you're facing in the +ve x direction, don't flood in the -ve direction), and simple analyses of chunklet data (e.g.: if an entire face of a chunklet is opaque, don't flood through that face)